# Trying to scale a view from it's top left corner

Tags: ios, swift

I have a child view controller whose view has been added as a subview on the parent view. I want to scale this by 1.1x from its top left corner. I tried doing this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.view.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
}

func scaleMyView() {
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.1, y: 1.1)
}
```

But that seems to re-centre the view over it's top left corner and then scale.

After reading some answers on here, I then tried setting the `position` of the view's layer like this:

```
let center = self.view.frame.origin
self.view.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
self.view.layer.position = center
```

But that moves the view somewhere to the center of the screen. How can I just make it scale from its top left corner without it moving in the parent view??

Comment: what about constrains?? messageLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
            messageLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 20)

Answer (score 1):

You're exactly right and extremely close. To change where a transform is anchored, you need to change the layer's anchor point. But when you do that, you need to change the layer's position to compensate, or the layer will move.

Let `self.v` be the view we want to transform:

```
let lay = self.v.layer
let p = lay.frame.origin
lay.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
lay.position = p
lay.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.1, y: 1.1))
```

Comment: Hmm, it still seems to be moving it into the middle despite changing my code to yours. I am calling this from within a child view controller and applying the transformation to its  view, does that make a difference?

Comment: Well, there could be more going on. But you didn't show that part! I don't even know what your code looks like at this point. However, I showed you _all_ of _my_ code. And I assure you that it works to apply a transform a view while keeping the top left fixed. Short of coming to your house and tapping keys on your keyboard I don't see what else I can do.

Comment: Expecting someone to post their _entire_ code is indeed ridiculous. Expecting a minimal verifiable reproducible example is not ridiculous; it is required. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example My code is sufficient to make a working example; I've told you everything you need to know. Now tell me everything I need to know to reproduce _your_ problem.

Comment: I've looked into this more using the debug view hierarchy. It turns out when embedding a child view controller using the storyboard, the child view controller's view is embedded inside another container view! So `self.view.layer.anchorPoint` is setting the anchor on the child view, but the child view "container" is still using a default anchorPoint, and that's causing the issue. Do you know how I can get around that?

Comment: Manipulate the container view instead of the child v.c.'s view? Personally I'm not a big fan of embed segues so this doesn't usually arise for me. I have no idea what your ultimate goal is, e.g. why you want to apply a transform to this view.